# How to convert json to yaml and vice versa in command line?

Tags: json, linux, command-line, yaml, converters

How convert JSON file into YAML and vice versa in command line?

Any ways are welcome.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Update: as of [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) version 4.18:**

The flags `-p` and `-o` let you specify input and output formats. You can convert between yaml, json, *and* xml!

```
yq -p json -o yaml file.json # json -> yaml
yq -p json -o xml file.json  # json -> xml
yq -p yaml -o json file.yaml # yaml -> json
yq -p yaml -o xml file.yaml  # yaml -> xml
yq -p xml -o json file.xml   # xml -> json
yq -p xml -o yaml file.xml   # xml -> yaml
```

**With [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) version 4.8.0:**

`yq e -P file.json` yields YAML

`yq e -j file.yaml` yields JSON

- `e` or `eval` evaluates each file separately. `ea` or `eval-all` merges them first.
- `-P` or `--prettyPrint` outputs YAML
- `-j` or `--tojson` outputs JSON

Comment: When using `-j` to produce JSON, more recent versions (e.g. 4.27.5) report `Flag --tojson has been deprecated, please use -o=json instead`

Comment: `--indent` is a useful option to define the indent of the output

Answer (score 4):

My python way:

1. create file `yjconverter`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json,yaml,sys,os

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
  print('Usage:\n  '+os.path.basename(__file__)+' /path/file{.json|.yml}')
  sys.exit(0)

path = sys.argv[1]

if not os.path.isfile(path):
  print('Bad or non-existant file: '+path)
  sys.exit(1)

with open(path) as file:

  if path.lower().endswith('json'):
    print(yaml.dump(json.load(file), Dumper=yaml.CDumper))
  elif path.lower().endswith('yaml') or path.lower().endswith('yml'):
    print(json.dumps(yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader), indent=2))
  else:
    print('Bad file extension. Must be yml or json')
```

2. add execution permissions and move file into bin:

```sh
chmod +x yjconverter
sudo mv yjconverter /usr/local/bin/
```

3. run `yjconverter some_file.json` or `yjconverter some_file.yml`
4. profit